# Vue-i18n undefined in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-i18n

I'm trying to implement a locale update using Vue, Vuex and VueI18n. I thought i found the way to update the locale setting the i18n value in the store object and then using it like this (mutation):

```js
    UPDATE_LANGUAGE: (state, newLanguage) => {
      state.language = newLanguage;
      this.$i18n.locale = state.language;
    }
```

But surprisingly doesn't work... it says this.$i18n is not defined, but it is.

[image]
[image]
Any thoughts??

```js
import store from "./store";
import EnMessages from "@/messages/en.json";
import EsMessages from "@/messages/es.json";

const i18n = new VueI18n(Vue, {
  es: EsMessages,
  en: EnMessages
});

i18n.locale = store.state.language;
store.$i18n = i18n;

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  //internacionalizacion en todas las urls
  request.url = `${request.url}?lang=${store.getters["getLanguage"]}`;

  //token en todas las urls
  request.headers.set("token", store.getters["getToken"]);

  next();
});

new Vue({
  i18n,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Try changing the method definition to:
`UPDATE_LANGUAGE: function(state, newLanguage) {`

Comment: it worked, but, i don't understand why... arrow function in es6 is supposed to keep the this of the whole object but not the traditional function()[]. Isn't this that way?? You can put it as an answer and i'll check it.

Comment: Please see my answer below - I tried to explain it a bit more in detail.

Comment: _"arrow function in es6 is supposed to keep the this of the whole object "_  that's not correct. The `this` for an arrow function is the context of where it is defined. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method declaration to:

```
UPDATE_LANGUAGE: function(state, newLanguage) {
    state.language = newLanguage;
    this.$i18n.locale = state.language;
}
```

**Here is why:**

You're declaring a new method inside a Vue component. If you are using the `function` keyword to declare the method then `this` will refer to the owner of the function, in this case the Vue component instance (which is what you want).

Using an arrow function on the other hand `this` does **not** refer to the owner of the function but `this` is taken from its context. You get an error that `this` doesn't exist there - and if it did it probably wouldn't be your Vue component.

Comment: You can also use the shorter function syntax `UPDATE_LANGUAGE (state, newLanguage) { ... }` which is the equivalent of what you have without using the `function` keyword